# OrderBy 3 different properties

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

In order for explanation purposes... let's say I have a table that is generated by a table in my database..

This table holds 3 pieces of information, `FlightDate`, `Aircraft`, `Pre / Post`.

So, the logic behind this is that there should be a *pre-flight* and a *post-flight* per day.

Now, for clarity, let's say the table so far looks like this:

```
  |Date|    |    |Aircraft|    |    |Pre / Post|

 04/08/2016 |     aircraft1    |      Pre-Flight
 04/08/2016 |     aircraft3    |      Pre-Flight
 04/08/2016 |     aircraft2    |      Pre-Flight
 04/08/2016 |     aircraft3    |      Post-Flight
 04/08/2016 |     aircraft1    |      Post-Flight
 04/08/2016 |     aircraft2    |      Post-Flight
```

As you can see there is no order by that table (except for maybe the date, but I just made this up).

Now what I would like to happen is when the page loads to display this table, for the table to be ordered by the `Aircraft` and it's `Pre / Post` based on the `Date`...

so essentially what I am looking for:

```
  |Date|     |    |Aircraft|    |    |Pre / Post|

 04/08/2016  |     aircraft1    |     Pre-Flight
 04/08/2016  |     aircraft1    |     Post-Flight
 04/08/2016  |     aircraft2    |     Pre-Flight
 04/08/2016  |     aircraft2    |     Post-Flight
 04/08/2016  |     aircraft3    |     Pre-Flight
 04/08/2016  |     aircraft3    |     Post-Flight
 04/09/2016  |     aircraft1    |     Pre-Flight
 04/09/2016  |     aircraft1    |     Post-Flight
 etc         |     etc          |     etc
```

Is there a way to use the *.OrderBy* method to achieve this outcome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain together multiple [`OrderBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) calls by following the first one with [`ThenBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ThenByDescending()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending(v=vs.110).aspx) respectively :

```
// This would order by FlightDate, Aircraft then PrePost
var aircraftFlights = context.AircraftFlights.OrderBy(a => a.FlightDate)
                                             .ThenBy(a => a.Aircraft)
                                             .ThenBy(a => a.PrePost);
```

Since you want your Pre-flight value to always precede your Post-flight values, you might consider explicitly using an `OrderByDescending()` for that column (as Pre- comes after Post- alphabetically) :

```
// Consider using ThenByDescending to get your Pre/Post ordering correct
.ThenBy(a => a.PrePost);
```

You can tailor this to suit your needs. Basically once you call your first `OrderBy()` call, your collection becomes an `OrderedEnumerable` which exposes the `ThenBy()` and `ThenByDescending()` calls and will handle chaining them together.

Comment: Beat me to it! ;)
Maybe you want to copy MSDN reference from my most to make it the complete answer?

Comment: All of my methods should have pointed to their respective MSDN references. The blue-on-gray always looks better than the plain gray IMO. :)

Comment: And you beat me to that as well. :D
Then there is nothing left to add.

Comment: Thanks @RionWilliams you have been a great help with most of my recent questions haha

Answer (score 2):

You can use OrderBy followed by ThenBy calls for each ordering constraint you want to apply. Assuming your enumerable you are ordering has all three properties it may look like this:

```
myEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x.Aircraft).ThenBy(z => z.PrePost).ThenBy(a => a.Date);
```

Comment: He wants to sort by date first.

Comment: That, and the OP would need to order by Date/Aircraft *before* `PrePost`. So the entire ordering here is wrong.

Comment: I was more attempting to show the syntax rather than worrying with the exact ordering the OP wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` using a lambda to evaluate the `Pre/Post` column. So something like this:

```
var orderedTable = table.OrderBy(t => t.Aircraft).
    ThenBy(t => t.Date).
    ThenBy(t => t.PrePost == "Post-Flight" ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ThenBy` extension of System.LinQ.

Your code might look like this:

```
var ordered = myFlights.OrderBy(f => f.Aircraft)
                       .ThenBy(f => f.prePost)
                       .ThenBy(f => f.Date);
```

For reference please check [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Not only is this basically a direct rip from the previous answer by DavidY, like David's answer, the ordering here is entirely wrong.

Comment: I only saw his post after I send mine and to be fair all answers are identical except for the order and I admit I misinterpreted that one.